# Creating custom button that gets a certain views block on the database

Tags: views, 7, database

Is there a way to create a custom button that gets a certain views block on the database upon click?

I want to write a custom function button that upon click, connects to the database, retrieve a certain view block, and displays it in a .tpl page.

Thanks.

Comment: where you want to create button..???

Comment: Maybe on a custom module and just call that button on the tpl.

Comment: if you are creating button on tpl then create it using html. i think to display a block you can use `$block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
print render($block['content']);`

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to invoke the block manually on the .tpl. I want to create a custom button or a custom module that gets / retrieves data from the database (table: views_display) and displays it on a page on a click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to use [modal form](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_forms) which uses ctool suites. Install exapmple and dependant module. Try create link or button just same as ajax form.

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer to my question? I wanted to create a custom button maybe a custom module that that upon click, connects to the database, retrieve a certain view block, and displays it in a .tpl page.

Comment: Have check with ctools ajax example?